# Is it possible to call DATE_ADD() in Java and store the value in a temporary date variable?

Tags: java, mysql, date

I have a doubt about adding days to `Date` in MySQL database.
The following is my code:

```
res=stat.executeQuery("select st_date from tmp1 where st_date = '"+t1.getText()+"'");
while(res.next())
{
    System.out.println(res.getDate(1));
    int i=0;
    while(i<14)
    {
        statement.executeUpdate("Insert into datetab values(DATE_ADD('"
            +res.getDate("st_date")+"',INTERVAL 1 DAY),'"+tempname+"')");
        i=i+1;
    }
}
```

All the updates in `datetab` table occur, but there is a problem. I will explain the problem with an example. If the date from tmp1 table is 28-12-2000, then after executing the insert query with `date_add()`, what happens is that 13 new inserts are happening, but all those inserts are "29-12-2000".

Comment: I don't actually understand what is your goal, but as far as i know in SQL, if you have "28-12-2000" date value as X, and you want to insert the next day is just: X + 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> If the date from tmp1 table is 28-12-2000 Then after executing the insert query with date_add(), what happens is that 13 new inserts are happening, but all those inserts are "29-12-2000".

Because that is exactly what you are asking for. Your insert statement is:

```
"Insert into datetab values(DATE_ADD('" + res.getDate("st_date") + 
    "',INTERVAL 1 DAY),'" + tempname + "')"
```

Since `read.getDate` is not changing in the loop, the same value is inserted in every interation.

Instead of `"Interval 1 DAY"`, use `"Interval " + i + " Day"` should insert different days. Is that what you are looking for?

Comment: Thanks brother...
I was imagining of that, I did that, but forgot to put the + sign, and an error was shown like incompatible types.
Thanks you. you saved me hour.

Comment: Didn't worked. There is no error, but that didn't update anything.

Comment: That's not likely, can it be a some other error in your code? I suggest you step through the program, assign the parameter to `executeUpdate` to a `String` and print it before calling `executeUpdate` and try it executing in an interactive sql session